# Should 'aerodrome' tag be a synonym of 'airport'?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Should [aerodrome](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aerodrome) (x6) tag be a synonym of [airport](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/airport) (x298)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I say yes, and suggested the creation of the synonym [pending votes](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tags/airport/synonyms).

While yes each has its own definition and slight variation in meaning, I don't think the broadness of aerodrome outweighs the prevalence of airport for most of the questions on the site such that it needs its own tag.

Update: synonym has been created.